# Why is my DNS Zone in Google Cloud not retrievable?

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform, dns-zone

I set up a DNS one on Google Cloud as follows:

[image]

Yet is still not retrievable:

```
me@machine:~$ nslookup wciel.pl ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com
Server:     ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com
Address:    216.239.32.109#53

*** Can't find wciel.pl: No answer

me@machine:~$ dig wciel.pl @ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> wciel.pl @ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 53429
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;wciel.pl.          IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
wciel.pl.       300 IN  SOA ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com. cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com. 1 21600 3600 259200 300

;; Query time: 7 msec
;; SERVER: 216.239.32.109#53(216.239.32.109)
;; WHEN: Fri Aug 02 11:17:59 BST 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 130
```

I'll appreciate any help.

Before you answer:

- Domain registry is pointing to the correct NS
- There is no A record I know, to my understanding it shouldn't matter

Comment: As was mentioned in a comment on your other question, without the actual domain name you're going to get very limited, and less than insightful answers. As it stands, the best answer we can give you is "Check your DNS". If you want answers that can help you address the actual issue then you need to tell us the domain name so that we can query it for ourselves and tell you what we find. Why are you obscuring the domain name? It's a publicly registered domain name. You're not "protecting" anything from a security standpoint by not telling us, you're just making it harder for us to help you.

Comment: You said: "When I created the Zone, it had ns-cloud-d* NSs as default, I edited it to c, maybe there's an issue there?" 99% that is going to be the problem. This is not something you can change by yourself and expect it to work.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I created new zone and left Data untouched. I still get the same answer for `dig` and `nslookup` queries.

Comment: @joeqwerty Sorry for not sharing the initial details. I registered new domain with the same setup and updated question with it. Let me know if you can think of anything more that would help troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: DNSstuff seems to think your DNS zone is OK - https://tools.dnsstuff.com/#dnsReport|type=domain&&value=wciel.pl

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your tests with nslookup and dig fail because there is no A record. By default, both commands use A as query type. Since you don't specify a different type of query, the commands request an A record for the name wciel.pl. You can see below how I could successfully get the NS and TXT records. However, when I asked for the A record there was no answer because it doesn't exist. As soon as you create a proper A record your commands `nslookup wciel.pl ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com` and `dig wciel.pl @ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com` should return the expected answers:

```
nslookup
> 
> 
> wciel.pl
Server:         172.16.245.40
Address:        172.16.245.40#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find wciel.pl: No answer
> 
> 
> set q=ns
> wciel.pl
Server:         172.16.245.40
Address:        172.16.245.40#53

Non-authoritative answer:
wciel.pl        nameserver = ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com.
wciel.pl        nameserver = ns-cloud-d2.googledomains.com.
wciel.pl        nameserver = ns-cloud-d3.googledomains.com.
wciel.pl        nameserver = ns-cloud-d4.googledomains.com.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
> 
> 
> set q=txt
> wciel.pl
Server:         172.16.245.40
Address:        172.16.245.40#53

Non-authoritative answer:
wciel.pl        text = "test wciel upd 14:38"

Authoritative answers can be found from:
> 
> 
> set q=a
> wciel.pl
Server:         172.16.245.40
Address:        172.16.245.40#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find wciel.pl: No answer
>
```